# iOS:Placing NSArray in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

I am doing application related to sending data to server and I had  array of values and when I am printing that array I getting the out put as below for the code

```
  NSArray *dataarray=[NSArray   
     arrayWithObjects:@"2",@"10",@"1",@"4",@"2",@"8",@"2",@"6",@"25",@"11",@"17",@"10",nil];

NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int i=0; i<[dataarray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *stringvar=[dataarray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:stringvar,@"x",nil];
    NSArray *ar1=[NSArray arrayWithObject:dic];
    [arr addObject:ar1];

}
```

when I print ""arr"" the result is below.

```
  [[{"x":"2"}],[{"x":"10"}],[{"x":"1"}],[{"x":"4"}],[{"x":"2"}],
  [{"x":"8"}],[{"x":"2"}],[{"x":"6"}],[{"x":"25"}],[{"x":"11"}],[{"x":"17"}]
```

but according to my requirement i need the whole array in string i..e in double quotes as like this

```
  "[[{"x":"2"}],[{"x":"10"}],[{"x":"1"}],[{"x":"4"}],[{"x":"2"}],
  [{"x":"8"}],[{"x":"2"}],[{"x":"6"}],[{"x":"25"}],[{"x":"11"}], [{"x":"17"}]"
```

i have tried keeping the array in string but its giving me a different bracketsby giving the arr  in string as below

```
 NSString *stringvalue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arr];
```

Its giving me wrong data i.e "(" of brackets as

```
"(\n(\n {\nx = 2;\n }\n ),\n(\n {\nx = 10;\n }\n),\n (\n                  
{\n x = 1;\n }\n ),\n(\n {\n x = 4;\n }\n    ),\n (\n{\nx = 2;\n}\n  
),\n (\n {\n x = 8;\n }\n),\n  (\n {\n  x = 2;\n }\n),\n (\n{\n x =  
6;\n }\n ),\n(\n{\n x = 25;\n}\n),\n (\n {\nx = 11;\n }\n),\n (\n               
{\nx = 17;\n }\n ),\n(\n  {\nx = 10;\n}\n)\n)"
```

But I dont need "(" kind of brackets I need as above result. Please help me how to change this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need a JSON array so use json serialization:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: how to remove \n then

Comment: `NSString *finalJsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccuranciesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];`

Comment: while iam printing in the console its fine while iam sending as a json data it look like [  [    {      \"x\" : \"2\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"10\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"1\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"4\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"2\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"8\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"2\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"6\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"25\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"11\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"17\"    }  ],  [    {      \"x\" : \"10\"    }  ]] with "\ " as a symbols how to remmove that please help me

Comment: In your NSURLRequest, you have to set `[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: are that slashes removed at the time before posting to the server ?but before posting that should be valid json format ?

Comment: The NSURLRequest should know that it will send json, so you  have to set the appropriate header for that using the code I've wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: yes but in my case its not working boss is there any other choices

Comment: Post the code for your NSURLRequest (where you send the data to the server)